lvm2 no available space even after delete file
I'm a dev working with docker. I made a stupid mistake building an image with a big database dump not ignore by dockerignore file. This result of 20g x 10 container make me out of available space. The second mistake, is i reboot after this.
So my filesystem wont reboot due to no more available space.
In rescue mode, i check.
root@recovery:/mnt/olddisk# lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/osvg/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                osvg
  LV UUID                gOiR1A-jN7h-XsTy-WiaN-tdwj-Rh4c-aAilWx
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time pop-os, 2024-03-06 21:48:30 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                8.00 GiB
  Current LE             2048
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/osvg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                osvg
  LV UUID                eSnfef-52O5-sy2C-zERF-0nc6-YMTY-y4gIzx
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time pop-os, 2024-03-06 21:48:54 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <463.94 GiB
  Current LE             118768
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
   
root@recovery:/mnt/olddisk# df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                  3.9G  2.7M  3.9G   1% /run
efivarfs               260K   82K  174K  32% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme0n1p2         4.0G  2.5G  1.6G  62% /cdrom
/cow                    20G  347M   20G   2% /
tmpfs                   20G     0   20G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                   20G  756K   20G   1% /tmp
tmpfs                  3.9G  1.7M  3.9G   1% /run/user/999
/dev/mapper/osvg-root  456G  442G     0 100% /mnt/olddisk
root@recovery:/mnt/olddisk# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/nvme0n1p3
  VG Name               osvg
  PV Size               <471.94 GiB / not usable 0   
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              120816
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          120816
  PV UUID               ckCCU4-4B5w-R4A5-hCjn-XzYv-ZF5W-vy8f1x
   
root@recovery:/mnt/olddisk# lvscan -a
  ACTIVE            '/dev/osvg/swap' [8.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/osvg/root' [<463.94 GiB] inherit

I try to delete some file and folder for making free space. but still 100% usage.
If someone has any idea, i don't want to reset all my system. I'v try :
delete some file
e2fsck
fsck
resize2fs


docker system prune?  Ah, you’re in rescue mode. You should probably find and delete those Docker images.

The fact that a LVM-backed block device is used to store the filesystem is not relevant. What's relevant is usage of the filesystem
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/osvg-root  456G  442G     0 100% /mnt/olddisk

Tells us 442GiB out of 456GiB so around 97% of the total space on the filesystem mounted on /mnt/olddisk is used. That means about 14GiB are free, but none of that is available to regular users as there is likely a proportion of the disk space reserved to root.
The default reserved space for ext4 file systems is 5% of the total space. If the FS is indeed ext4 (df -T will tell you), you can check the settings (as root) with:
tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/osvg-root |
  grep -e Reserved -e Block.size -e Free

Which should give you something like:
Reserved block count:     419430
Free blocks:              887453
Free inodes:              1575965
Block size:               4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)

(in my case, I have more Free than Reserved blocks so there is still space available).
Here you'd need to either free an extra 2% or change the amount of space reserved to root with tune2fs -m

As @Stéphane Chazelas already mentioned, you need to free up space.
Normally, Docker stores the images under /var/lib/docker if you haven't changed the path.
I would try to identify the image you created and delete it manually.
Most of the time, the images are split and shared in this folder.
Pay particular attention to large folders in overlay2, containers, or image.
Find the large folders that are consuming the disk space with (adjust the path if it’s incorrect) :
sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /mnt/olddisk/var/lib/docker
